# Setting a variable equal to a returned value from a for loop in Python

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

This would save me a lot of code, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I would like to set my variable "totalfactors" to the result of a for loop iterating through a dictionary and performing a product operation ([Capital Pi Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation)). So I would think I would write this like:

```
totalfactors = for x in dictionary: dictionary[x]*totalfactors
```

I know I could write this out in a couple lines like:

```
totalfactors = 1

    for pf in apfactors:
        totalfactors *= (apfactors[pf]+1)
```

Any help would be quite useful! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) built-in [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce). It will repeatedly (or recursively) apply a function - here an anonymous lambda - on a list of values, building up some aggregate:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x * (y + 1), [1, 2, 3])
12
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
>>> (1 * (2 + 1)) * (3 + 1)
12
```

If you need another initial value, you can pass it as the last argument to reduce:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x * (y + 1), [1, 2, 3], 10)
240

>>> (((10 * (1 + 1)) * (2 + 1)) * (3 + 1))
240
```

Like @DSM points out in the comment, you probably want:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x * (y + 1), [1, 2, 3], 1) # initializer is 1
```

which can be written more succinctly with the [operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module and a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) as:

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> reduce(mul, (v + 1 for v in d.values()))
```

---

I would have guessed, that the generator variant is faster, but on 2.7 it seems it is not (at least for very small dictionaries):

```
In [10]: from operator import mul

In [11]: d = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}

In [12]: %timeit reduce(lambda x, y: x * (y + 1), d.values(), 1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit reduce(mul, (v + 1 for v in d.values()))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 us per loop
```

Comment: Is it better to use a lambda or `operator.mul`?

Comment: Note that by my reading of the OP's second example, he'd actually prefer 2*3*4=24 for the answer.  I'd probably do something like `reduce(mul, (v+1 for v in d.values())`.

Comment: With a small dictionary, the generator overhead swamps the speed improvement.  Add a few more items and the generator variant catches up and becomes faster.  For me the crossover was at 6 key/value pairs in the dictionary.

Comment: @torek, well my machine still runs the benchmark over 1M entries. At 100000 both variants were on par (4.41s vs 4.4s).

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps by the time you reach 1M the arithmetic takes over.  I only did 3, 4, 5, and 6 under timeit.  In any case, speed is implementation-dependent, as usual. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may want to look into doing a reduce(). For example:

```
>>> d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, d.values())
24
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to think of a way to do this with a generator, but all I could come up with was

```
import operator
total_product = reduce(operator.mul, dictionary.values(), 1)
```

I tested it with:

```
factorial = reduce(operator.mul, xrange(1,6), 1)
```

which gave 120 as a result.

Edit:

You probably already know this but I thought about it later. If you have any non-numeric data in `dictionary.values()` values, you'll get a `TypeError`, provided that you have at least one `float`. You're probably handling that when you insert into the dictionary, though.

I messed around a bit and came up with:

```
import numbers
import operator

foo = [1, 2.1, None, 4.5, 7, 'm']
print reduce(operator.mul, [num for num in foo if isinstance(num, numbers.Number)], 1)
```

Which gave me 66.15 and no exceptions. It's probably less efficient, but it is more efficient than an unhandled exception.